# What's the song when the army returned defeated in episode 1 of Shingeki no Kyojin?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

In episode 1 around 9:14, there's a song playing when the army returned from outside the wall defeated.

What's the song title?

Answer (score 1):

The soundtrack you're looking for is called **Shingeki** **pf20130218** **Kyojin** ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoNxTS5YYG0&t=84m50s)). However, the melody you mentioned does not immediately start.

Comment: dead link. maybe this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgD6FyLgGD4